# Use clojureql or STM + asynchronous writes?

Tags: caching, clojure, persistence

I am writing an application in clojure which needs to persist its data, but if some data is lost then it is not disastrous. I am wondering whether I should use ClojureQL every time I want to access data or should I use the STM + ClojureQL and just persist data asynchronously on updates/writes. Does anyone know any advantages/disadvantages of each approach. And has anyone tried the asynchronous persistence approach?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a classic approach to improving write latency, often called write-behind.  Batching together updates and doing them in a separate asynchronous thread has several benefits:

- removes (presumably slow) writes to persistent store from the update path
- more efficient if you can batch updates
- might allow coalescing of updates (if you have multiple writes on the same key in the same batch, you can just kill off all but the last and never write the intermediate value at all)

Write-behind also has significant disadvantages:

- writes can be lost if the data is stored only in memory
- it is sometimes challenging to get the background async thread to participate properly with the rest of a transactional system
- the background thread(s) can get backed up since they are handling the "slow" part of the operation; write-behind works best when it's used to speed-up occasional peaks and can recover during the troughs
- subsequent reads between the memory-write and the store-write will see the old value unless you also check the in-memory state - that can be either confusing or potentially expensive on read.  Because of this, write-behind is often used in conjunction with read-through caching where all reads occur through the cache.

None of this really has anything to do with ClojureQL or the STM of course.  :)

Comment: Perfectly reasonable approach.  Watcher(s) on some relevant refs can push stuff to your datastore every N changes/seconds/transactions/whatever.  Some of the new diffing functionality in Clojure 1.3 HEAD might be useful in determining degree of shift from a previously-persisted "snapshot", or in allowing you to persist only those bits of the referenced data structures that have changed.

Comment: do you have a link to more information about this doffing? I would like to try it out